# Noetherian ring is finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, axiom-of-choice, noetherian

I just saw someone prove the equivalence for a commutative ring $R$:

(1) $R$ is Noetherian;

(2) Every ideal of $R$ is finitely generated;

(3) Every non-empty set of ideals of $R$ has a maximal element.

For $(2) \Rightarrow (3)$, he used the axiom of choice (although Zorn's Lemma would have been more direct). Suppose I would only want to prove $(1) \iff (2)$, could there exists a proof without AC, or is that impossible since (1), (2), (3) are in fact equivalent?

(I have already proven $(2) \Rightarrow (1)$, so in fact my question pertains to $(1) \Rightarrow (2)$.)

Comment: Are you sure this is in fact a duplicate? The post you refer to seems to deal only with (1) and (3). It makes sense that _there_ AC is needed, because it is about maximal elements which immediately sends you to Zorn, i.e. to AC, whereas I'm only interested in finite generation.

Comment: I think I've found the answer. In a ring with the ascending chain condition, a maximal element of my arbitrary ideal presents itself immediately. Quite obvious actually, if I see it correctly.